# Make a Index for a report

Tags: indexing

I have to put a index on my report because the report is too long. How I create and what packages I have to use to make a index for a report? I need a index appropriate to a report. I wanna the index in the second page of my report. (after the cover)

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{imakeidx} 
\makeindex[program=xindy, options=-C utf8 -L portuguese]
\begin{document} 
\printindex 
\begin{abstract} Estudou-se o valor da acelera\c{c}\~{a}o grav\'{i}tica
\end{abstract} 
\section{Objectivos do Trabalho} 
A finalidade da experi\^{e}ncia\index{finalidade da experi\^{e}ncia} de: 
\end{document}
```

Comment: `makeindex`, `imakeidx`, `xindy` ... Say you want the index, mark the items to be indexed and print the index at the appropriate point in the document. Compile, run `makeindex` or `xindy` or neither as required. Compile.

Comment: @cfr I wanna use the package `imakeidx`. Is necessary, when I make `\index{key}` that the key belongs to the text? I wanna put the abstract in the index, but the word abstract doesn't belong to the text. Is that possible?

Comment: It makes no sense to put the title of the abstract into the index. My advice would therefore be not to do it regardless.

Comment: @cfr Ok thanks for advice. How I can put the entries of the index? The keys of the index have to be in the text? And if I wanna other words to my keys? When I print index, it stay in the second page?

Comment: It would be rather easier to help you if you provided a minimal example document. If you want working code with an index as an example, provide working code without an index for people to start from. The index will stay in the second page if you ask for it to printed at a point in the source which turns out to be on the second page and if the index is no longer than one page. Like anything else except floats, it will print where you put it.

Comment: @cfr (...)`\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=xindy, options=-C utf8 -L portuguese]
\begin{document}
\printindex
\begin{abstract}
Estudou-se o valor da acelera\c{c}\~{a}o grav\'{i}tica
\end{abstract}
\section{Objectivos do Trabalho}
A finalidade da experi\^{e}ncia\index{finalidade da experi\^{e}ncia} de: \end{document}` I make this but the index doesn't appear.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code. It doesn't belong in a comment. Highlight the code and use the `{}` or ctrf+k to format it correctly.

Comment: Did you run `xindy` as Bernard said and then recompile?

Comment: @cfr This is probably the issue. Compiling with `Latex` first and then with `xindy`, and `Latex` again.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest making it with `xindy`, which has the advantage to understand `utf8` if you have accented letters. Loading the `imakeidx` package, you obtain the index in one compilation.

You need two commands: `\makeindex[options to pass to the index compiler]` in the preamble, and `printindex` at the place where you want it in your document. However, unless I've missed something, there seems to be one restriction: `\printindex` has to be used only after all items are indexed. The `index{…}` commands which appear afterwards won't be written in the `.idx` file.

Here is a code:

```
\documentclass[portuguese]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}%
 \usepackage{imakeidx}%
\makeindex[program=xindy, options=-C utf8 -L portuguese]%

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract} Estudou-se o valor da aceleração gravítica\index{valor}
\end{abstract}
\section{Objectivos do Trabalho}
A finalidade da experiência \index{finalidade da experiência} de:

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really need your index at the beginning of your document, you can load the `makeidx` package, insert the `\makeindex` command in the preamble and `\printindex` in the document body. Then compile with `pdflatex + makeindex + pdflatex`. As accented letters are not understood by `makeindex`, you have to index items with `\index{sortingtext@text-with-accents}`. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[portuguese]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}%
 \usepackage{makeidx}%
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\printindex
\begin{abstract} Estudou-se o valor da aceleração gravítica\index{valor}
\end{abstract}
\section{Objectivos do Trabalho}
A finalidade da experiência \index{finalidade@finalidade da experiência} de:

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I never make a index on Latex. Can you explain me, please, how I make everything on an index? I cannot make a index, I don't know where to start... I'm completely lost

Comment: Please see my completed answer. Hope I've been clear enough.

Comment: (...)`\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[program=xindy, options=-C utf8 -L portuguese]
\begin{document}
\printindex
\begin{abstract}
Estudou-se o valor da acelera\c{c}\~{a}o grav\'{i}tica
\end{abstract}
\section{Objectivos do Trabalho}
A finalidade da experi\^{e}ncia\index{finalidade da experi\^{e}ncia} de: \end{document}` I make this but the index doesn't appear.

Comment: Could you post a fully compilable code?

Comment: `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} \usepackage{imakeidx} \makeindex[program=xindy, options=-C utf8 -L portuguese] \begin{document} \printindex \begin{abstract} Estudou-se o valor da acelera\c{c}\~{a}o grav\'{i}tica \end{abstract} \section{Objectivos do Trabalho} A finalidade da experi\^{e}ncia\index{finalidade da experi\^{e}ncia} de: \end{document}`

Comment: @CarmenGonzález Please edit your question to include the code.

Comment: I think this answer would be far more useful to a complete (index) novice if it were actually an MWE. A truly exemplary answer would also include the steps involved in getting to the final product (with the file extensions so the novice could understand what file is for what purpose).

Comment: @CarmenGonzález: I modified my answer. You don't have any index because it seems `imakeidx` takes into account only the `\index` commands  written *before* `\printindex`, for some reason. There's a workaround using the older `makeidx` package and `makeindex` (the program).

Comment: @jon: I modified my answer to take into account your pertinent remark. Doing so I found out a problem with `imakeidx`: `\printindex ` has to be used *after* all items have be indexed.

Comment: +1. The 'after' issue is very frustrating. In law books, it is common to have a 'table of jurisprudence' at the *start* of the work (following the table of contents), and an index would be the most appropriate tool for the job. (I keep meaning to look into this problem, but it's never pressing enough....)

Comment: @Jon: Maybe ask to the author of `imakeidx`. I must say I don't understand why it is so. Perhaps because it is designed to be one-pass.